# HTML table Align

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create the table with two `td`. But the problem is TD can't align properly if more than one `td` used.

Image:

[image]

Here is code:

```
<table style="width: 100%; font-family: Arial sans-serif; margin-top: 20px;" border="1">
    <tr style="background-color: #133B6C; padding: 5px; color: white;">
        <td style="float: left;" colspan="2">

            <b>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" CssClass="lblDetails" runat="server" Text="Comments"></asp:Label>
            </b>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <th>approvers</th>
       <th>approvers</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added `style="float:left;"` in your `td`. Remove that and it will work. You can use `style="text-align:left"` to keep the text in left.

Answer (score 0):

Don't `float` table cells. It overrides `display: table-cell`, so the element isn't laid out in the normal way and `colspan` has no effect.

Answer (score -1):

Add align="justify" in place of style="float: left;"
Here is the example: